# escaped filename slashes

Tags: string, bash, escaping

I want to generate filename from a user-inputed string and to make sure that it is safely escaped.

for example, if the user enters `/usr/bash` the output will be `\/usr\/bash`
and if the input is `The great theater` the output is `The\ great\ theater`.

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: -1 for not specifying exactly what needs to be escaped and, more importantly, why.

Comment: I had similar problem: needed to add another backslash to escape an existing backslash. For example, changing c:\home to c:\\home.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you need to do this? This is kind of a code smell. There's very likely a better way to do whatever you're trying to do than mangling your input. Properly quoting your variables when you use them usually suffices:

```
$ file='some file name.txt'
$ touch "$file"
$ ls "$file"
some file name.txt
```

If you insist, though, use the `%q` format with printf:

```
$ str='The great theater'
$ printf '%q\n' "$str"
The\ great\ theater
$ escaped=$(printf '%q' "$str")
$ echo "$escaped"
The\ great\ theater
```

Note that this won't escape slashes as they aren't normally special characters.

Comment: I'll second the "code smell" comment, and also add that what needs escaping and how it needs to be escaped depends a lot on exactly what is going to happen to the string.  printf %q does quoting suitable for interpretation by bash.  If you need to escape for, say, use in an SQL query, that's a different set of escape rules.  If it's going to be interpreted by bash and then SQL, it needs to be double-escaped (and in the right order)!